# R: export code with formatting and line numbers to Microsoft Word

Tags: r, formatting, ms-office

This is probably a little bit an off-topic question to programming but I have to copy a great amount of code into a report written in Microsoft Word (Mac 2011 version).

I am looking for a way to export my R code with the line numbers.

Up until now I just opened my code in R (eventhough I am normally using RStudio) and copied and pasted it with the colorised formatting from there to Word (which gave me a nice touch to it). But is there a way how I could also get the number of lines copied for an easier overview of the code as it is not only short snippets of code but several pages of code?

Does any of you have experience with this? What are you using when publishing your code to a report (I know about exporting to pdf and using a LaTex solution but this still doesn't solve the problem with the code line number)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Word has line numbering facilities. You can do by section, page, or document:

file:///Applications/Microsoft%20Office%202011/Microsoft%20Word.app/Contents/Resources/en.lproj/Help/art/Pod_WD_Layout_TextLayout.gif

[image]